# 'Sh' object has no attribute

Tags: python, networking, ip

I am trying to list all the ip addresses on my network and i found this code but i ran into this problem. it is showing that sh has no attribute.

i have tried many things like importing pbs and turning sh into a class.
i am currently using windows 10 and running the latest python version.

```
import pbs
class Sh(object):
    def getattr(self, attr):
        return pbs.Command(attr)
sh = Sh()

for num in range(10,40):
    ip = "192.168.0."+str(num)

    try:
        sh.ping(ip, "-n 1",_out="/dev/null")
        print("PING ",ip , "OK")
    except sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:
        print("PING ", ip, "FAILED")
```

i should see a list of the ip addresses i belive but instead i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scanner.py", line 11, in <module>
    sh.ping(ip, "-n 1",_out="/dev/null")
AttributeError: 'Sh' object has no attribute 'ping'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scanner.py", line 13, in <module>
    except sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:
AttributeError: 'Sh' object has no attribute 'ErrorReturnCode_1'
```

Any Help?

Comment: `ping` isn't defined anywhere in your `Sh` class

Comment: better see module [sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/). It can run `sh.ping('-c', '1', '8.8.8.8')`

Comment: on [this page](https://pypi.org/project/pbs/) I found information that module `psb` changed name to [sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/)

Comment: instead of external module `sh` you can use standard module `subprocess` - ie. `returncode = subprocess.run('ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null', shell=True).returncode`.  Or  `returncode = os.system('ping -c 1 8.8.8 > /dev/null')`

Comment: to check hosts in network you can use tool like [nmap](https://nmap.org)(Network MAPper) - [How to find live hosts on my network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36198/how-to-find-live-hosts-on-my-network). There is also python wrapper for this [python-nmap](https://bitbucket.org/xael/python-nmap/src/default/)

Comment: so could you show me the code to display the ip addresses on my local network?

Comment: @furas could you show me what the full code would look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on Linux.

(Documentation for Windows' [ping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping))

---

With module [sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) it should be

```
import sh

for num in range(10, 40):
    ip = "192.168.0." + str(num)

    try:
        sh.ping(ip, "-n 1", "-w 1") #, _out="nul") # Windows 10
        #sh.ping(ip, "-c 1", "-W 1") #, _out="/dev/null") # Linux
        print("PING", ip, "OK")
    except sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:
        print("PING", ip, "FAILED")
```

Windows 10 doesn't have device `/dev/null` (which exists on Linux) but probably it can use `nul` to skip text.

On Linux it doesn't display text even without `_out` so maybe it will no need `_out` on Windows.

Linux uses `-c 1` to make only one ping. Windows `-n 1` or `/n 1`. I also used `-W 1` to timeout after 1 second - so it doesn't wait too long for response. Windows probably use `-w 1` or `/w 1`

---

With module `pbs` probably you have to only replace all `sh` with `pbs`

```
import pbs
```

and

```
except pbs.ErrorReturnCode_1:
```

but I don't have this module to test it.

---

With standard module `os` it needs `/dev/null` on Linux

```
import os

for num in range(10, 40):
    ip = "192.168.0." + str(num)

    exit_code = os.system("ping -n 1 -w 1 " + ip + " > nul") # Windows
    #exit_code = os.system("ping -c 1 -W 1 " + ip + " > /dev/null") # Linux

    if exit_code == 0:
        print("PING", ip, "OK")
    else:
        print("PING", ip, "FAILED")
```